# Why do I have to set cacheName when using the expiration plugin?

Tags: workbox

When using the [Workbox expiration](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.expiration.Plugin) (4.1.1) I get the following error:

```
You must provide a 'cacheName' property 
when using the expiration plugin with a runtime caching strategy.
```

Why can I not just let Workbox use the default cache that it generates as part of its default configuration?[1]

1. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/configure-workbox

Answer (score 1):

cache name is mandatory when using the expiration plugin since v3.

> Using cache expiration in a strategy without also supplying a cache name is no longer valid. In v2, this was possible: ...
>
> This would lead to expiring entries in the default cache, which is
>   unexpected. In v3, a cache name is required: ...

source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v2